# Connecting a LAN drive to Windows 2008 / 2012 VM instance on Google / AWS / Azure

Tags: virtualization, amazon-web-services, virtual-machines, azure, google-compute-engine

**Scenario:**
Our office uses a Sage software on multiple workstations. The software is individually installed on each workstations, but the database is stored on a server tower that has shared access to all computers via a LAN switch as a network drive. Whenever people want to access the software, we've been utilizing RDP.

**Goal:**
I want to setup Windows VM instances on the cloud, and install the software on the cloud instance, so I can eliminate the need for the local machine.

**Question:**
Can I map a local drive from a LAN server to a Windows VM instance?

Comment: If the software is individually installed on each workstation, I'm wondering why are people using the software via RDP?

Comment: Sage is everything that is evil in the world.  Workarounds like this are completely normal with their products.

Comment: @Kamran Sometimes people want to access the Sage CMS off premise. This is a very old setup.

Comment: @Hyppy Cannot agree more! I have experience with other CMS and this is definitely not the most user friendly. But it does take a bit of preparation to migrate to another one. I'll just have to try and work with what we have for now. In the future, it will very likely be SaaS, which would be a breeze!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a site-to-site VPN connection, If your users are on different LAN networks, you have to option to create a point-to-site VPN connection.

technically, both options will allow your VM to appear as if it's in your local LAN, you will have the ability to map network drives with this.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-network/

PS: If you're only interested in using a shared folder inside a VM, perhaps "Azure File storage" will be a better option than using a VM: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can setup your Sage software installation on Google Cloud.
For connecting your current LAN infrastructure or local drives to your Cloud server, you can use Google Compute Engine VPN as described in this article:  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn